# Query on filling "IMM 0008 General application form for Canada"

Tags: canada, immigration

To apply for provincial nominee certificate from `Saskatchewan`, [SINP](http://www.economy.gov.sk.ca/immigration/express-entry) is requesting to submit `IMM 0008 general application form for Canada` along with provincial forms.

In this general application form, there is a field:

`Category under which you are applying` to be answered, as shown below.

[image]

As per the above screenshot, Is it relevant to select option, `provincial nominee program` or `skilled worker` ?

Comment: I couldn't find any reference to this in the various SINP guides. My guess is that you should put provincial nominee program.

Comment: @mkennedy ok. am selecting `Program under which you are applying` as `economic`. Is that fine?

Comment: Yes, choosing economic looked correct to me.

Comment: Yes, that was the correct option